# iframe sent the default user agent to the server before the script applies a new user agent to it

Tags: javascript, iframe, user-agent

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function setUserAgent(window, userAgent) {
    if (window.navigator.userAgent != userAgent) {
        var userAgentProp = { get: function () { return userAgent; } };
        try {
            Object.defineProperty(window.navigator, 'userAgent', userAgentProp);
        } catch (e) {
            window.navigator = Object.create(navigator, {
                userAgent: userAgentProp
            });
        }
    }
}
setUserAgent(window, '__MY AGENT__');
var vframe = document.getElementById('vframe');
if (vframe.contentDocument){
setUserAgent(vframe.contentDocument, '__MY AGENT__');;
}
else if (vframe.contentWindow){
setUserAgent(vframe.contentWindow, '__MY AGENT__');
}
document.write(window.navigator.userAgent); // __MY AGENT__
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<iframe height="100px" width="100%" src="embed.php" id="vframe"></iframe>
```

I changed the `userAgent` via javascript. But, here in `embed.php` the userAgent seems not to be changed. I guess that is because iframe sent the default user agent to the server before the script applies a new user agent to it. I tried to do this via javascript too:

```
document.write('<iframe height="100px" width="100%" src="embed.php" id="vframe"></iframe>');
```